# Функциональное программирование в javascript

Tags: javascript

Изучаю Erlang, попробовал написать что-то вроде аналога встроенной функции "свертки" `lists:foldl`, на javascript:

```
foldl = (fn, x, list, acc) => {
  try {
    if(!acc) {
      acc = 0;
    }
    if(!list.length) {
      return acc; 
    } 
    return foldl(fn, x, list, acc + fn(list.shift(), x));
  } catch(e) {
    return 0;
  } 
};

console.log( foldl((x, y) => x + y, 2, [1,2,3]) ); // 12
```

В этом примере "повышается уровень абстракции", соблюдена чистота функции. Приемлимо ли писать (или пытаться писать) код полностью в функциональном стиле, как в Erlang, на javascript? К чему это может привести в конечном счете?

Comment: Функции в js описываются проще - рекурсия допустима.  `=>` тут лишний.

Comment: вы сделали функцию [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: правда не совсем корректно :-)

Comment: @Grundy не претендую на авторство )

Comment: @MatveySafronov, честно говоря не понял вопрос, какой именно ответ ожидается?

Comment: @Grundy можно ли полностью код писать такими вот функциями? помимо чисел будет что-то другое в них вычисляться. пишут ли так на продакшенах? ) императивный код будет где-то глубоко в классах, а на верху - только функциональный код

Comment: Можно. Архитектура React/Redux это даже требует местами.

Comment: Данный код кстати не функциональный, изменяется начальная переменная `list`

Comment: Почему бы и нет? Пишите как вам нравится. Для javascript есть масса библиотек для программирования в функциональном стиле - Bacon.js например. И даже трансляторы с функциональных языков - Clojurescript, например.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо, буду смотреть